# Twitter widget or tools displayed feeds that I follow?

Tags: java, javascript, twitter

Are there any tools, api in java or javascript to mainly read the account a Twitter user is following???

Comment: Have you looked at the Twitter API Docs: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api

Comment: @ stepanian yes I did, but all the doc I could see was focused on twitter user only. And I didn't how to formulate my question within google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(edited) you may check friends and folloowers section in [Spring Social](http://static.springsource.org/spring-social-twitter/docs/1.0.x/reference/html/) or check [Twitter API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api)